# Using AngularJS and Select2

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-select2, ui-select2

I'm trying to use select2 tags drop-down.

I call the API which sends me data. I put the data into select2 like this :

```
AssignmentProvider.getStudentsInCourse(COURSENAME,SEMESTER)
.success(function(data) {
    $scope.select2OptionsForGroups = {
        'multiple': true,
        'simple_tags': true,
        'formatResult': formatResult,
        'formatSelection': formatResult,
        'tags': data
    };
})
.error(function(e) {
        // TODO: Error handling
        console.log("error");
});
```

data being array with objects of students, so I fetch the Names inside the object with this.

```
 function formatResult(student) {
        return student.id.Student.FullName;
    };
```

Everythings works perfect when I select the first name from the dropdown list, but when I try to select the second it's like there is nothing in the list to select but if I remove my existing selection all the names come back in.

Here I'm select the second one and nothing happens :

[image]

and here is when I have not selected anyone.

[image]

It's displays the names when I click but when I enter in search term is shows

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'FullName' of undefined
```

**Updated:**

Has anyone any idea what might be wrong here, I'm guessing I need to tell the select2 to search for the term inside the object but how?

Comment: Can you provide more code, include the selection function? Can put together a plnkr that shows it?

Comment: What more code do you want to see, I think I have posted everything that involves this.

Answer (score -2):

My initial guess would be that you have some data entries where Student is undefined